# javascript push the an object into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am learning the sample code of the canvas circle motion trail effect. I am bit confusing with the `push(x:Pos,y:Pos)within the`storeLastPositio()function, the sample code are as below:

```
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var xPos = -100, yPos =170;

var motionTrailLength = 10;
var positions = [];


function storeLastPosition(xPos,yPos){
        positions.push({
            x: xPos,
            y: yPos
        });
    if (positions.length > motionTrailLength){
            positions.shift();
        }

    }



function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    for(var i = 0;i<positions.length;i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(positions[i].x,positions[i].y, 50,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle='green';
        ctx.fill();
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(xPos,yPos,50,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF6A6A";
    ctx.fill();

    storeLastPosition(xPos,yPos);
    if(xPos > 600){
        xPos = -100;
    }

    xPos +=3;

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();
```

I just bit confusing the `push()` part inside the `storeLastPosition()` function, is this called as pushing the object properties into the array?

Comment: That function (`storeLastPosition`) is adding new coordinates to array and remove the previous ones if the length exceeds from `motionTrailLength` value.
What's confusing to you?

Comment: just inside the store function push({x:xPos,y:yPos}), is a bit straightforward for me to see pushing object like this, so the {x:xPos,y:yPos}is the anonymous object which stores the x/y position right?

Comment: Yes. Basically it stores an object literal that has two properties `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `push` method mutates an array in place to add a new element to the end of the array. In this case, you're adding a new Object to the array, rather than the properties. So, your array will contain objects of x/y positions.

see [the MDN Docs on Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for more information